# How to find code examples built into eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

A friend showed me some time ago how to find some snippets of code that were built into eclipse to give an idea how these pieces of code were formed.

For example, it showed the basic premise of how a for loop and how a while loop should look. It also gave examples of how arrays should be formed etc.

However, now i don't remember how to access these snippets of code so that i can gain a simple idea of how they should be formed.

I won't be able to just get it from the internet, as during the exam that is coming up for me soon, they won't have access to the internet and will only be able to use things built into eclipse.

Comment: normally, those examples won't be there either. if you really need examples to know how a for or while loop have to be written, you're not ready for the exam anyway.

Comment: @Stultuske is right; if you have a Java-based exam coming up, you should learn off by heart the structures of loops, datatypes and so on. It will also help you going forward.

Comment: I'll try my best. I'll have a nosy around for loops and while loops and try to practice and learn them.

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look on Eclipse predefined Snippets at:

```
Window -> Show View -> Other -> General -> Snippets
```